# IntegrityError: music_song.album_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, html, django

I'm Django beginner and facing this error "music_song.album_id may not be NULL" and i was trying to solve this error but unfortunately can't solve it. i put almost all my code here so please Django Experts review the code and let me tell from where i did a mistake?

**Views.py**

```
def model_form_upload(request, pk):
    all_song = Song.objects.all()
    print'\n-------------------------------------------------------'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.FILES
        form = SongForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            songName = request.FILES['audio_file'] #getting song name
            fs = FileSystemStorage() #allocate memory
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(songName) #getting url of uploaded file
            form.save() #song saved

            return render(request, 'music/model_form_upload.html', {'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url, 
                                                              'form': form})
    else:
        form = SongForm()
    return render(request, 'music/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form, 'all_song': all_song})
```

**forms.py**

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('song_title', 'audio_file')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .validators import validate_file_extension


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.artist


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    audio_file = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_extension], max_length=500)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/upload/$', views.model_form_upload, name='upload')
```

**model_form_upload.html**

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>



 {% if uploaded_file_url %}
        <strong>Song:</strong>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="{{ uploaded_file_url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>


          <h2>Modal Example</h2>
          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                  <strong>Song:</strong>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="{{ uploaded_file_url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no album_id passed into your context, so this error message pops.
So in your modelform, add an album field.

**forms.py**

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('song_title', 'audio_file', 'album')
```

Then get the album in your view and pass the album.id into your context.

**views.py**

```
def model_form_upload(request, pk):
    all_song = Song.objects.all()
    print'\n-------------------------------------------------------'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.FILES
        form = SongForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            album = request.POST['album'] #getting the album object
            songName = request.FILES['audio_file'] #getting song name
            fs = FileSystemStorage() #allocate memory
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(songName) #getting url of uploaded file
            form.save() #song saved

            return render(request, 'music/model_form_upload.html', {'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url, 'form': form, 'id': album.id})
    else:
        form = SongForm()
    return render(request, 'music/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form, 'all_song': all_song})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i did same but now new error are showing: 

MultiValueDictKeyError at /1/upload/: "'album'"
album = request.FILES['album']

Comment: I've updated my code. Test `album = request.POST['album']`

Comment: thank now it's working fine but the problem is when i create a song so everytime i have to select Album also and there are hundreds of albums..

Comment: i'm creating a song at selective album and my URL look like: (http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/upload/) so "1" is a pk of album. can we get this pk of album and direct pass to the song instead of everytime selecting the album?

Comment: You can try:
`album = album.objects.get(id=pk)`

Answer (score 0):

it's just because you're trying to create a song without an `Album` instance, based on your models structure `album = your models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, you set the album field `non-null`, so the `ForeignKey` can't remain empty or Null.

You can either set that field nullable and instead of `models.CASCADE`, you just add `models.SET_NULL` plus a signal `/pre_delete/post_delete` to album in order to delete all the songs related.

```
 class Album(models.Model):
     artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     ''' codes '''

 class Song(models.Model):
     album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  null=True,blank=True)

 @receiver(pre_delete, sender=Album)
 def delete_songs_with_album(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     instance.song_set.all().delete()
```

Or you can instead of having the field `album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` in Song, you change your models structure a little bit by removing that field, and add new field `ManyToManyField` to `Song` in `Album`

```
 class Album(models.Model):
     artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     songs = models.ManyToManyFIeld('Song',blank=True)
     ''' codes '''

 class Song(models.Model):
     # REMOVE album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Remove 
     ''' fields '''
```

You can still have the signal in the latter case to delete all the songs with an Album

Comment: you said "you're trying to create a song without an Album instance" so please could you please tell me about how i can make Album instance while creating a song?

Comment: you can add the field in your Model Form, this will display an HTML select in template where you can choose albums that are already in db. or before saving your song **if you want to create a New Album while creating song**, In your view after submitting the form, with the parameter `commit=False`, you create a new record for Album, and add this  instance to song, then `save()`. If something is not clear, let me know

Comment: as you know i'm a beginner so if you can give me the example with the code so i'll thankful to you

Comment: before I suggest anything... do you want really to create an album when creating creating a song. I mean a song might not have an album, like a single

Comment: I creating a song at a selective album and my URL look like: (127.0.0.1:8000/1/upload) so "1" is a pk of album. can we get this pk of album and direct pass to the song instead of changing models etc

Comment: and i have many albums so i want to get album id and direct pass to the songs as i have gave you example at above comment